# Google Sign in (javascript) whilst inside iOS webApp giving white screen

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, google-signin

I have been facing a few issues regarding Google Sign in whilst inside a Web App.

Google Sign in API works perfectly when inside Safari, but when I run it as a webApp (adding to home screen with `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` It simply shows a white screen.

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated!